# How can I convert a python object to string using the context?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-sekizai

I am trying to render object instances in django templates the way forms do it. So somewhere in a view an object instance gets created: `my_object = MyObject()` and passed to the template in the context: `context['my_object'] = my_object`.

When the template is processed, the `__str__()` method of `MyObject` is called to create a string to be filled in. For `MyObject` it looks something like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    """ Render template """
    return mark_safe(
        render_to_string(self.template, {'options': self.options})
    )
```

Since the object's template would like to add code to the CSS and JS blocks using sekizai, I need the rendering context. Is there a way (e.g., using an different method) to get this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that is not possible and it's *not the Django way*!

What I would do is this:

1. Declare a template (named like `mymodel_repr.html`).
2. Write inside it, exactly how I would like to be rendered.
3. Store it among the other templates (maybe in the app's `templates/` folder too).
4. Change the `__str__(self)` to return a `required` field or something else.
5. Now, each time I want to print an object (in a template way with all the context) of this model, I would simply [`include it`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#include) like this: `{% include 'mymodel_repr.html' with obj=obj_i_want_to_print %}`.

With this method you are seperating the business from the presentation.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks very much! I fully understand the template part. Not sure what you mean with step 4 and the ``__str__(self)`` being a required field. ``include`` is a great way to go. I would change it to ``{% include obj_i_want_to_print.template with obj=obj_i_want_to_print %}`` to let the object select which representation it will be printed.

Comment: I mean that if the `__str__` returns a model field then this field should be a not nullable one. If it just returns a plain str, then diregard this step!

Comment: One more thing: I have come across comments that s.th. is not the Django way. Just wanted to ask what you mean. I believe Django forms use ``__str__`` to print forms in templates.

Comment: I don't understand your question (especially the *s.th* part)!

Comment: Nik_m, you mentioned that my approach "is not the Django way". My question: Where and how do I potentially violate Django principles without being aware?

Comment: Now I get it. I said it because of the request-response cycle. Your logic tries to reverse it somehow (access the `request` object inside your models). As Django docs says `A model is the single, definitive source of information about your data`. `Models` should have no awareness of the context. That's all!

Comment: Absolutely, Nik_m! My object is not a model but a graph (so it lives on the view side). Still ``include`` is the way to go. Just had another thought on it: I could add a ``render``method to it and use ``{% include obj_i_want_to_print %}``.  This would call the render method with context. Thanks once more for the excellent discussion!

Comment: Ok, then! Go ahead with the `include`. Best regards!